# Sobolev spaces for conformal metrics on a Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, sobolev-spaces, conformal-geometry

Suppose we have a compact Riemmanian manifold $(M^n,g)$ without boundary, and some class $\{g_u\}$ of conformal metrics $g_u:=e^{2u}g$, where $\{u\}\subset C^\infty(M^n)$. For some $k,p$ suppose there exists a constant $C_1=C_1(g)$ such that each $u$ in this class has corresponding $W^{k,p}(M^n,g_u)$-norm bounded by $C_1$:
\begin{equation}
||u||_{W^{k,p}(M^n,g_u)} \leq C_1. 
\end{equation}

Can we conclude there exists $C_2=C_2(g)$ such that  each $w$ in this class has $W^{k,p}(M^n,g)$-norm bounded by $C_2$, i.e. 
\begin{equation}
||u||_{W^{k,p}(M^n,g)} \leq C_2?
\end{equation}

UPDATE: The only thing I can think of is if $p$ is high enough then from Sobolev embeddings we get a bound on the Holder norms, but is this uniform in $g$? I should think uniform bounds on the Sobolev norms does imply uniform bounds on the Holder norms. If this is the case, then in particular we get uniform bounds on all the functions $u$, in which case just doing conformal transformations in the integrals (see the comments) answers in the affirmative.

Comment: Your two inequalities seem to be identical - can you clarify the difference?

Comment: Preliminary comment: I think this would follow by rewriting the volume element of $g$ in terms of that of $g_u$, then writing the $L^p$ norms of $u$ and its gradient using the change of variable formula. I would then use the compactness and the fact that these $L^p$-norms with respect to the volume element of $g_u$ are bounded. I haven't done the computations but maybe this argument would be enough. EDIT: In my mind I read $K=1$ :(

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis yes sorry, the second one shouldn't have a subscript $u$. I have edited.

Comment: @Sak In doing this we would get exponential terms in the integrals of the form $e^{\alpha u}$. I'm not sure if these integrals can be uniformly bounded in terms of the metric $g$ since we do not have uniform bounds on the functions $u$.

Comment: But your manifold is compact right? So for sure these would be bounded I think.

Comment: @Sak Yes each $u$ would be bounded, but that doesn't imply a uniform bound on all $u$ in our class (which may be infinite)? Unless I'm missing something very obvious.

Comment: Is your assumed bound even possible? Seems to me that taking $u$ to be arbitrary large constants will always make $\|u\|_{k,p;g_u} \to \infty$.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis I am considering a very specific class of $u$ (in my instance, solutions to some non-linear PDE). The class doesn't necessarily have to contain any constant functions.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis And to be clear, in my specific case I have shown the above to be true! I am now wondering whether it holds in more generality, although maybe the question requires some additional assumptions on the class of functions $u$

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense. I assumed "some class of conformal metrics $g_u = e^{2u} g$" meant the entire conformal class, i.e. all $u\in C^\infty.$

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Hopefully I've edited it to make it a little clearer :) Perhaps this is something more suited to MathOverflow? It's late in the day and I've lost the ability to tell whether I'm missing something obvious

Comment: I think there's a decent chance you can resolve this here. I think you will at least need to assume something like a lower bound on $u$ - as stated, I believe the class of constant functions $\{ -k : k \in \mathbb N\}$ provides a counterexample.